# JavaScript callback function return undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write two functions. One contains elements of array with `forEach` method and another is a callback function that access elements of array from the first function and `log` their length. The second function is not working and throws  `Uncaught ReferenceError`. I wonder why I get this error.

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Mango", "Apple"];
fruits.forEach(listFruits);

function listFruits(allFruits) {
  console.log(allFruits);
}

function countFruits(callback) {
  callback(allFruits);
  console.log(allFruits.length);

}

countFruits(listFruits);
```

how can i fix this `error`? and access the `length` of elements in my `callback function` , any help will be appreciated

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Well, you haven't actually defined `allFruits`. It's just the name of an incoming function argument. What do you expect its value to be?

Comment: `callback(allFruits);` -> allFruits is not defined in this scope. This is a variable defined only in the scope of listFruits function.

Comment: @ 
kelly
 i want to print length of all fruits in callback function

Comment: `callback(fruits.length)`

Comment: I really am not sure what you think the code is actually doing. What are you trying to get exactly? What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: @isherwood  ok is there any solution?

Comment: @Barmar demonstrate the solution

Comment: so result is [6, 5, 5] possibly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to call a function using an array as prop

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Mango", "Apple"];
fruits.forEach(listFruits);

function listFruits(allFruits) {
  console.log(allFruits);
}

function countFruits(callback) {
  // the following line is the problem, "allFruits" are not defined.
  // if you change the prop to the array "fruits" the error is solved
  callback(fruits); 
  console.log(fruits.length);

}


countFruits(listFruits);
```

Answer (score 2):

`allFruits` is a local variable in the `listFruits` function, you can't access it outside the function.

Instead, `countFruits` should take its own `allFruits` parameter. Then it can call the callback function, passing `allFruits.length` to get it logged.

```js
const fruits = ["Banana", "Mango", "Apple"];
fruits.forEach(listFruits);

function listFruits(allFruits) {
  console.log(allFruits);
}

function countFruits(callback, allFruits) {
  callback(allFruits.length);
}

countFruits(listFruits, fruits);
```